# Magento2 : Change custom attribute scope not working

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, scope

I create a product custom attribute programatically. The scope was WEBSITE. But now I just realised that this attribute must have the scope as STORE, because I need different values according to the store view.

I changed the scope in backend, clean the cache, and when I went to edit the product, the scope was correct [STORE]. Then I change store, view so I can insert the value for the store view and the scope changed to [WEBSITE].

I went back and the scope was wrong again [WEBSITE].

I went again to the attribute (Stores > Attributes > Product), choose my attribute, and the attribute had the right scope. I didn't change anything, only save the attribute again and clean the cache. Then I edit the product and the scope was correct [STORE], then I change store view and the scope was wrong again [WEBSITE].

I check database and the attribute is ok.

Did this happening to anyone? 
Anyone has a clue about this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You've probably solved your problem, but here is solution for people coming here from google as me. I've managed it by editing it straight in database.

**It's not recommended** to do such things - **the safest way is to delete this attribute and add it again**, but sometimes you have no choice. This is e.g. how to change attribute scope to GLOBAL.

```
UPDATE catalog_eav_attribute SET is_global = 1, apply_to = 'simple,virtual,configurable' WHERE attribute_id = YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_ID;
```

And then refresh cache.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this command:

```
bin/magento indexer:reindex

bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: I did this already and didn't solve the issue. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can save scope of custom category attribute like this using upgrade schema:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Custom\Setup;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Category;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    /**
     * @var EavSetup
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * UpgradeSchema constructor.
     * @param EavSetup $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        EavSetup $eavSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.0.5', '<')) {
            $setup->startSetup();
            $this->eavSetupFactory->updateAttribute(
                Category::ENTITY,
                'custom_attribute',
                'is_global',
                ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                null
            );
            $setup->endSetup();
        }
    }
}
```